# Convert CURL code to Google Apps Script code

Tags: google-apps-script, curl, urlfetch

I try convert this curl code to GoogleAppsScript

curl --location --request POST 'http://mpstats.io/api/wb/get/category?d1=2020-07-13&d2=2020-08-11&path=%D0%96%D0%B5%D0%BD%D1%89%D0%B8%D0%BD%D0%B0%D0%BC/%D0%9E%D0%B4%D0%B5%D0%B6%D0%B4%D0%B0' 
--header 'X-Mpstats-TOKEN: 5edfe8277ff2a5.941835169784f269a9244f13350db36eedb814d1' 
--header 'Content-Type: application/json' 
--data-raw '{"startRow":0,"endRow":100,"filterModel":{"id":{"filterType":"number","type":"equals","filter":13495594,"filterTo":null}},"sortModel":[{"colId":"revenue","sort":"desc"}]}'

but part of code : "startRow":0,"endRow":100 = don't work

I try this code in Google Apps Script
let optionMpStats ={
headers: {
'X-Mpstats-TOKEN':  token,
'Content-Type': 'application/json'
},
payload: JSON.stringify({
'startRow':0,
'endRow':10,
})
};

Comment: Do it without `JSON.stringify()`

Comment: Although I'm not sure about the detailed valid values of the request body, if you use `UrlFetchApp.fetch(url, optionMpStats)` I think that the request of your `optionMpStats` is the same as your showing curl command. So, can I ask you about the detail of `but part of code : "startRow":0,"endRow":100 = don't work`? And, can you provide the document of the API you want to use?

Comment: documetation of the Api https://mpstats.io/integrations

when I try change endRow for example put  "endRow":20 
I getting all the time 100 rows